# Unable to generate values from dynamic fields created PHP|Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get the right results from looping through rows generated when calling a function in php but i only get one row generated not all the rows. Below code of what i have.

```
<form method="post" action="done.php">
<div id="add_passenger">
  <div class="fields">  
   <input type="text" name="field[email]" />
   <input type="text" name="field[name]" />
 </div>
<button type="button" onclick='add_field_row();' ">Add Email</button>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div> 
</form>

$dynamicEmailFields = $_POST['field']
<?php
    foreach($test as $key => $fields) {
       //Here i want to output the field name and value depending on the 
         number of row generated when calling add_field_row() For instance:
         email1: email1@mail.com
         name1: john doe
         email2: email1@mail.com
         name2: john doe

       //With this result from the loop it means that there were 2 rows generated.  
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the actual code look like?

Comment: You would need to modify the JS, but inputs are overwriting each other, you would need `name="field[email][]"` and  `name="field[name][]"` OR `name="field[0][email]"` and `name="field[0][name]"`

Comment: AbraCadaver - got it and then how would you loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array of inputs.  This would be the easiest to loop:

```
<input type="text" name="field[0][email]" />
<input type="text" name="field[0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="field[1][email]" />
<input type="text" name="field[1][name]" />
```

Then:

```
foreach($_POST['field'] as $field) {
    echo 'email: ' . $field['email'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'name:  ' . $field['name']  . '<br/>';
}
```